# Does LINQ enhance the performance by eliminating looping?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-objects

I've used Linq against some collection objects (Dictionary, List). So if I want to select items based on a criteria I write a Linq query and then enumerate the linq object. So my question is that is Linq eliminating looping the main collection and as a result improving the performance?

Comment: LINQ is not magic.

Comment: I saw someone pull an IEnumerable<Rabbit> out of a hat once.....

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Absolutely not. LINQ to Objects loops internally - how else could it work?

On the other hand, LINQ *is* more efficient than some approaches you could take, by streaming the data only when it's required etc.

On the third hand, it involves extra layers of indirection (all the iterators etc) which will have some marginal effect on performance.

Comment: Aha! I *knew* you had three hands.

Comment: So I see that Linq-to-Objects is inefficient in 'non unusual' scenarios.

Comment: Oh gawd... not this again. @NLV, how do you quantify inefficient? Given that coder time costs much more that hardware (even rented hardware), and the time savings that Linq provides... coupled with the fact that usually around 90% of one's code is non-performance critical, I'd say that not using linq is inefficient.

Comment: @NLV: It's likely to be *very marginally* less efficient than hard-coding everything - but your code will be *much* more readable.

Comment: ...but running .NET is not *very marginally* less efficient than natively compiled code, so we should be using that instead. :)

Comment: Actually, if we all wrote optcodes it'd probably be faster, and wouldn't require a compiler. We should all switch to that.

Comment: Can we just get all the way down to butterflies now and get this over with?

Answer (score 2):

Probbaly not. LINQ lends itself to terse (hopefully) readable code.

Under the covers it's looping, unless the backing data structure supports a more efficient searching algorithm than scanning.

Comment: "unless the backing data structure supports a more efficient searching algorithm than scanning" - This is, in general, not true, unless that optimization has been *specially* built into that query operator. For example, `Skip` is not optimized for lists as far as I know. And there's currently no way for a collection to "hook into" a LINQ to Objects query.

Comment: My point is that the backing data structure might *support* it, but LINQ to Objects may not use this support.

Answer (score 1):

No, in fact if you are using LINQ to SQL, the performance will be a little worse because LINQ after all is an additional layer on top of the ado.net stack.

if you using linq over objects. there are optimizations done by linq, the most important one is "Yield" which starts to yield results from an IEnumerable as it gets generated. which is better than the standard approach which has to wait for a List to be filled and returned by the function in order to iterate over it.

Comment: LINQ to SQL: true as long as both queries end up being the same.  If you're pulling back everything then using LINQ to objects to do filtering, it could be slower.  LINQ to objects: If you already have a pre-filled list, then it won't be faster.  It all really depends on what's going on behind the scenes.

Answer (score 1):

When you use the query directly, then you still loop over the whole collection.
You just don't see everything, because the query will only return elements that match your filter.
The overall performance will probably even take a hit, simply because of all those nested iterators that are involved.
When you called ToList() on your query result, and then used this result several times, then you'd be better off performance-wise.